# Custom Model Form Recognizer in Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can I use created Custom Model of Form Recognizer in Logic App? I am getting an error '***Specified model not found or not ready, Model Id: XXXXXXX***' while using Analyze Custom Form of Logic App. What is the correct way of using Custom Model in Logic App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using that along with form recognizer studio?

The current form recognizer task only supports the previous version of the API.
Note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/tutorial-logic-apps) it says "This tutorial and the Logic App Form Recognizer connector targets Form Recognizer REST API v2.1 and must be used in conjunction with the FOTT sample labelling tool"

Form Recognizer Studio is available with the v3.0 API. ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/concept-custom#form-recognizer-studio))

Some time ago I posted an alternative way using the logic App Http task ([here](https://brunolucas.blog/2022/08/02/using-logic-apps-with-form-recognizer-studio/)).

You can try using that or use the concept to do something like a custom adapter until they release a task that works with 3.0

Comment: I am using the Form Recognizer Studio that comes along with the Form Recognizer service in Azure Portal. 

So, the point is that if I create anything from there, it won’t work as of now since it is creating for v3.0. I need to use the Fott sample labelling tool to create the model which can then be used in the Logic App as it has a task of using v2.1 and not v3.0.

Comment: Should I use this link to create the custom model for v2.1 - https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/  ?

Comment: Hi, yes, if you want to use the currently available form recognizer task in logic apps you will need to use  fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net. not sure when there will be one for the new form recognizer studio. if you want to use the new form recogniser studio you can follow that approach i suggested with http tasks and upgrade later.

Comment: You just need to consider migration case you use  fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/v3-migration-guide   - If any of this info helped, you may want to vote or mark as an answer to validate that and help other users. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, got it.. Thanks for the help BrunoLucasAzure..